# Can I skip cutscenes in Far Cry 4?

Tags: far-cry-4

Due to the buggy nature of Far Cry 4 (and every major release lately it seems) I've sat through the 20 minute cutscene intro 2 times now, and I will gouge out my eyes if I have to do it again (patches changed something with save, etc;).

Is there a skip intro movie button I missed?

Answer (score 19):

No you can actually skip the intro :)

To do it you need a shortcut on your desktop, right click on it and select ‘Properties’. In the ‘Target’ box simply add “-skipintro” (minus the quotes) and click okay to confirm. For the Far Cry 4 intro skip to work, Far Cry 4 must be launched through the desktop executable rather than through your Uplay library.

Comment: Interesting workaround, I followed your advice and was able to skip the cutscene.

Comment: Neither this nor northkildon's solutions works for me. Has anyone got this to work for the steam version? The steam version opens, uplay, which opens steam again. I'm guessing the flag is lost in between. I was trying to launch it from `".../bin/FarCry4.exe" -skipintro`

Comment: I'm fairly sure that -skipintro will skip the intro splash videos before you get to the main menu (nVidia, etc.), but it won't affect any in-game cutscenes and videos.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, the method only skips the startup videos. It also apparently no longer works with the Uplay version: http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Far_Cry_4#Skip_intro_videos

Answer (score 9):

No you didn't miss anything, there are no buttons/ways to skip those unskippable cutscenes.

As horrible as it sounds, you'll have to watch them over and over again whenever a bug occurs, or you can go make dinner and dance a bit too if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, I ended up ALT-TAB ing out of the game and then hitting the Windows key to free my cursor, the game ran silently in the background while I was free to do other things for 20 min ;)

Answer (score 5):

And to skip the intro in `Steam` right-click Far Cry 4 in your library, then choose `Properties`, then go to `SET LAUNCH OPTIONS`:

[image]

enter '-skipintro':

[image]

and click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Comment: I'm fairly sure that -skipintro will skip the intro splash videos before you get to the main menu (nVidia, etc.), but it won't affect any in-game cutscenes and videos.

Comment: @FeralChimp: That's true, the command only skips the startup videos.

Answer (score 0):

maybe bit late, but just a thought..
download a gamespeed changer, most known would be cheat engine. Set hotkeys for normal speed and a faster speed (maybe x10). if a cutscene comes on, just fast forward till you can play again. Dont know if this is a possibility.

Comment: If you don't know, it's better to post a comment (which I know you cannot do yet).